# Что означает единица в классе "col-xs-1-12"?

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap

Постоянно сталкиваюсь с таким автокомплитом в пакете `atom-bootstrap3`, но не смог найти вразумительного ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Устанавливает какую часть пространства должен занимать блок 1/12 или 12/12 . В стандартной сетке бутстрапа 12 размеров от 1 до 12 указывающие отностельную ширину. 12 это вся ширина. 1 это 1/12 от всей ширины.